# Is there a reason for using unions today (when we have so much available memory)?

Tags: c, unions

As I understand it, unions are a way to use memory chunk for several purposes. Is there a reason to use a union in our days, where memory is not an issue?

Obviously my question does not regard using limited HW that can be found on some small embedded devices.

Comment: Yes, because it's just good code hygiene not to waste space when you don't have to?

Comment: They're not just about saving memory - you use them when you are storing a value that could be of many different types.

Comment: Why people are thinking `union` is for saving memory? They are absolutely not.

Comment: @ChrisTurner That can be solved by creating each variable by itself and assigning to the right type - that seems more readable, IMO

Comment: Unions allow for type-punning

Comment: These "limited HW that can be found on some small embedded devices" probably constitute an overwhelming majority of all CPUs in the world (just like rodents and bats constitute 75% of all mammals).

Comment: So, you'd implement a variant data type simply as a `struct` containing members of every type it can possibly have, then just leave the unused members consuming memory pointlessly?

Comment: when mapping structs over the top of HW defined memory areas, io ports, registers etc.

Comment: @underscore_d It's kind of opinion-based. In a small case - yes, I would rather have 2 variables instead of a union. I'm not convinced that usage of unions keeps my code cleaner

Comment: @ChristianGibbons: keep in mind that unions allow for type punning only as a non-standard compiler extension.

Comment: Yes, it's very opinion-based. I'm not sure it's fertile ground for a useful discussion, for that reason. If *you* don't want to use them, them don't. But you don't have to go far to find examples of why *others* need to use them.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Why aren't they?

Comment: @underscore_d I hoped to hear not opinion based :)

Comment: My main reason for using unions has never been for saving memory. Performance and code simplification is rather it.

Comment: @MichaelBurr No, it's only non-standard in C++.  In C it is standard as of C99.

Comment: @CIsForCookies but that defeats the point of only allowing one member of the union to be valid at a time and they're no less readable than a struct as they use the same syntax for dereferencing

Comment: By the way, the reasoning "we have so much memory", "we have so much disk space", "we have such a fast processors" - so we don't have to think about performance - is simply *wrong*. This reasoning is leading to the over-bloated and poorly performing software we see everywhere today. Come on, it's hard to find a tick-tack-toe game today in less than 10M package...

Comment: @MichaelBurr - I'm only looking at n1570, and not the official standard. But [6.5.2.3p3](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.3p3) indicates that reading a member that wasn't previously written is not an immediate undefined behavior. And this [footnote](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note95), while I agree is not normative, suggest the spirit of the above clause, and of the things in 6.2.6.1 is to allow punning. So I wouldn't say it's a non-standard extension per se.

Comment: Well - I learned something new today.  C is more permissive on accessing union members that weren't stored to than I remembered. My apologies to @ChristianGibbons.

Comment: "Is there a reason to use a union in our days, where memory is not an issue?"  --> Memory is always an issue.  More memory now handles bigger problems.  Inefficient memory usage is also slower.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Arguably, saving space is a side effect of defining a union. The primary reason for having a union is enabling creation of structures with only one active member at any given time.

```
struct StringOrInt {
    enum {String, Int} kind;
    union {
        char *str;
        int num;
    } val;
};
```

Although one could argue that `union` above could be replaced with `struct` when memory is not an issue, this would misrepresent the purpose of the structure to readers of the code, who would assume that both `str` and `num` could be set under some valid circumstances. Using `union`, on the other hand, makes it clear to the code readers that the intention is to set either `str` or `num`, but never both of them at the same time.

Answer (score 4):

There is reason. I have seen codes even now which use them as `variant` types.

```
struct my_vartype_t {
    int type;
    union {
        char char_value;
        int int_value;
    };
};
```

Now based on the `type` it will use necessary union value. This is a very trivial example here but it is used in many cases to provide a code with compact data association ( by this we mean that not scattering unnecessary redundant types rather one clean way to the variant type).

As mentioned by AndrewHenle these are some examples of using unions in *real-world* [**`XEvent`**](https://linux.die.net/man/3/xevent), [**`struct sockaddr`**](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/basedefs/sys/socket.h.html).

Comment: Real-world (almost) example:  [`struct sockaddr`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/basedefs/sys/socket.h.html), where `sa_family` is the "type".  (I say "almost" because the various `struct sockaddr_*` types are not necessarily implemented as a union.)  Even better example:  [`XEvent`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/xevent).

Comment: @AndrewHenle.: Oh..yes...I have added these examples ..check the answer

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if using them improves performance, then use them without second thought.

Aside from that, they can be used as a very easy way to access variables from intrinsics (when debugging, because apparantly, there is a performance penalty to doing this).

Comment: I enthusiastically disagree with the blanket statement that performance should override all other considerations. Priority must be given to writing readable and maintainable code, and optimisations should only be applied once working code is written, a bottleneck is known, and the potential gain in performance does not bring concomitant losses in other aspects of the code.

Comment: @underscore_d However, optimizing later instead of immediately can also waste time, since code dependencies will most likely be interrupted.

Comment: I didn't say there weren't potential pitfalls either way. I said that 'always prioritise performance without thinking about anything else' is bad advice. I'm not advising people to deliberately write inefficient code at the outset, but rather to think about the sense of the code above its performance aspects, at least until the latter are known to be limited.